# hibernate doesn't remove child with named query, but removes with session.delete()

Tags: hibernate

I am not an expert with hibernate, as stated in the subject, I have an Object with a Collection of object in it.
I tried to use a

```
session.delete(myObject)
```

and the entity with all the related children gets correctly removed from the database.

However when I run a simple named query:

```
<query name="deleteByID">
    DELETE FROM MyObject o WHERE o.objId IN (:objIds)
</query>
```

And then in the code

```
Query deleteQuery = s.getNamedQuery("deleteByID");
deleteQuery.setParameterList("objIds", objIds);
return deleteQuery.executeUpdate();
```

but only the main entity is removed, while the children remain in the database.
The collection is correctly marked as delete-orphan. I wanted to know why such behaviour, and if it's possible how to achieve the complete removal with named queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known issue, hibernate does not perform cascade delete via HQL. If you load the object and delete it using `session.delete(object);` then the cascade relations are respected. Not via HQL. You have either of the 3 options.

- Load them and call `session.delete();`
- Load all the child items via HQL, delete them, and then the real objects.
- Put a cascade link at the database level. So when you delete it, the DB will take care of it.

Read more here: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=944722&start=0